# Symfony2: render inside block causes duplicate sub request

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a Sf2 application with a twig template extending a layout. Inside the template i want to fill a block by using twig's `render` tag. Unfortunately the `render` tag causes **two** sub requests instead of the expected single one. But if i place the `render` tag **outside** of the block, everything works just fine*.

*of course except that the result is rendered simply at the top of the page instead inside a block, but it's only one additional sub request.

***What may cause that two sub requests are made if - and only if - the `render` tag is placed within a block?***

---

## DIRTY DETAILS

In the layout there's a block for an additional navigational menu (`topmenu`):

*layout.twig.html*

```
            <div class="row" id="secondary-nav">
                <div class="span12">
                    {% block topmenu %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

### Duplicate sub request example

And this is my view, it uses a `{% render ... %}` tag to fill the `topmenu` block by issuing a sub request to the "Navigation" controller:

*index.html.twig*

```
{% extends "FooBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block topmenu %}
     {% render "FooBundle:Navigation:index" with { 'active': 'feedback' } %}
{% endblock %}
```

So far, so good, but doing it this way the sub request is issued **twice** for some unknown reason. It's not displayed twice, but i see the SQL query count increased and the symfony2 profiler shows two identical sub requests too.

### Single sub request example

If i place the `{% render ... %}` tag outside of any block like this, it is causing only one single sub request:

*index.html.twig*

```
{% extends "FooBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% render "FooBundle:Navigation:index" with { 'active': 'feedback' } %}

{% block topmenu %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NARF! Finally, after spending X hours on this issue, i found out that i had a check in my `layout.html.twig`, to see if the `topmenu` block has any contents:

```
{% if block('topmenu') %} ... {% endif %}
...
{% block topmenu %}{% endblock %}
```

This led to the second, unwanted sub request.

**Fix**

To still have the ability to check for the content but not requesting twice, i'm loading the block into a variable first and then outputting the variable instead of using `{% block topmenu ...%}`:

```
{% set topmenu = block('topmenu') %}
{% if topmenu %} ... {% endif %}
{{ topmenu | raw }}
```

Luckily i do not need to extend the block really, it's just a placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Wouldn't have thought of that in the first place. That might spare me X hours in the future.

Comment: Careful using the `raw` filter because it actually causes auto escape + auto unescape.

Comment: Use `{% autoescape false %}{{ top_menu }}{% endautoescape %}` instead.